# Relationship among different abstract algebra constructs

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a rudimentary understanding of rings. I wish to know how they are related to other abstract algebra constructs. To that end, I tried to use a Hasse diagram. I welcome corrections and comments. What is the most hazy to me is that how a vector space is equivalent to a module.

[image]

Comment: I'd start with groupoids/monoids if i had done this and build from there. I doubt there'd be any perfect diagram. Vector spaces should be a sub category of modules.

Comment: Vector spaces over a field $K$ are $K$-modules by definition. What is "most hazy" about it?  Small typo in the diagram: "communtative" abelian group. Modules over  a ring $R$ are called [$R$-modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). They form an abelian category $\mathcal{M}od_R$. For $R=\Bbb Z$ we obtain back abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks again, Dietrich. I'm a self-taught beginner. What does "over" mean? What are modules over a ring $R$ called, if there are such things? I used the word "with". Is its usage correct in this context? How's "over" differ from "with"?

Are the following statements correct?

A vector space is equivalent to a module with a field of scalars.
A module with unity is equivalent a vector space with a ring of scalars.

Comment: @ChanTaiMan modules over a ring are just modules. Fields are rings, so modules over fields are a perfectly fine construct. And for historical reasons (and because they are much better behaved than other modules), they also get a name of their own. So "vector space" and "module over a field" are synonyms.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Now, I get it that "vector space" and "module over a field" are synonyms. 

I need a little more time to think about how a module over a ring is another module. I'll get back to that. 

BTW, should I use the word "over" not "with".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Vector spaces over a field $K$ are $K$-modules by definition. Modules over a ring $R$ are called $R$-modules (though a different kind of module from the original one). What are vector spaces over a ring? PS Typo corrected.

Comment: "Over a ring" only means, that the set acting on the module is a ring $R$. So the scalars acting on the module are elements of $R$. It is the same "over" as we have in a vector space "over" a ring - which is an $R$-module.